# Android Sdkmanager CLI for Mac not downloading packages

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded the `tools` package (which contains Android sdkmanager tool) on my mac inside a folder called `myfolder`.

I started a New terminal window inside the folder called `tools/bin` and wrote the following command:
`./sdkmanager "package-name"`

The command executes successfully asking to accept the license agreement of the package. When I accept the agreement, the required folders for the package are created outside the `tools` folder but it hangs after that and no actual package gets downloaded.

Do I have to do something else or determine a certain path in `bash_profile` for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the package is actually downloading in the background but due to the lack of a progress bar and my poor internet connection, it seems that nothing is happening.

Moreover, the downloaded files are copied to a folder after the whole folder components get downloaded.

Thanks!